# Datastax spark cassandra connector - writing DF to cassandra table

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

We have recently started big-data project using Scala, Spark and Cassandra and I am new to all of these technologies. I am trying to do simple task write to and read from cassandra table. I am able to achieve this if I keep property names and column names all either in lowercase or snake case (unserscores), but I want to use camel case in my scala code. Is there any better way to achieve this using camel case format in Scala and snake case in cassandra.

we are using

> scala - 2.10.5 spark - 1.6.2 datastax spark-cassandra-connector -
>   1.6.0 cassandra - 3.0.9.1346 datastax enterprise - 5.0.3

Cassandra table

```
CREATE TABLE dev.castable (
id int PRIMARY KEY,
long_name text,
name text,
short_name text)
```

Scala code

```
    val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setAppName("TestHelper")
        .setMaster("local")
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.01")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    println("writing data to cassandra")
    val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(List(new MyRow(2,Option("long name"), "ss", Option("short name"))))
    df.write //*** this is not working
      .cassandraFormat("castable", "dev")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()

    println("reading data from cassandra") //*** This is working fine
    val rdd = sc.cassandraTable[MyRow]("dev", "castable")
    rdd.foreach(println)
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Columns not found in table dev.castable: longName, shortName
at com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns.selectFrom(ColumnSelector.scala:38)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:268)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSourceRelation.insert(CassandraSourceRelation.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:222)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
at com.aktana.spark.util.LocalTestDriver$.main(LocalTestDriver.scala:38)
```

I read that spark-cassandra-connector automatically does this conversion automatically but it is not working for me.
[datastax spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/4_mapper.md)

Comment: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-370 - Currently Dataframes behave as is.

Comment: Thanks Russ, I am able to solve it using RDDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RDDs, spark-cassandra-connector automatically converts camel cased properties to underscored column names. Thanks again [RussS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1174164/russs)

Here is how I am saving case class objects to cassandra table

```
    val writeRDD = sc.makeRDD(List(new MyRow(2,Option("long name"), "ss", Option("short name"))))
    writeRDD.saveToCassandra("dev", "castable")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your MyRow definition doesn't match with cassandra table definition. Try this:

```
val df = List((1, "My Long Description", "My Name", "My Short Name")).toDF("id", "long_name", "name", "short_name")
```

Comment: Specifying column names looks good for simple use cases like this. But I want to save a complex object with many nested `case classes`. Is there a way to convert camel case properties to snake case column names on the fly?